# Similar Tor-related question for Linux and Mac OS X

Tags: discussion, exact-duplicates

I was going through [tor](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/tor) to see what I could see, and I came across and answered this question which asks about Mac OS X:

[How do I tell tor, from the command-line, to give me a new identity](https://superuser.com/questions/330064/how-do-i-tell-tor-from-the-command-line-to-give-me-a-new-identity)

Further down, I came across what I think is essentially the same question, but phrased differently, and asking about Linux:

[How to “flush tor circuit”](https://superuser.com/questions/138262/how-to-flush-tor-circuit)

Initially I was going to flag as a dupe.  But, I think the different phrasing and operating systems involved may mean that there is some value in having both questions open, perhaps linked to each other in the comments.

On the other hand, we could edit the second question a bit to ask about POSIX-compatible OSs and include the two different phrases ("New identity", "flush circuit") though this would do some violence to the OP's actual question.

What do you think that we should do here?

Comment: Thanks for the input all.  In the interests of following the will of the community, and also a bit out of laziness, I'll let sleeping dogs lie.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Considering this isn't a widespread issue across many questions in the [tor](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/tor) tag, and might well be system dependent (e.g. if one uses some GUI to control TOR) I'd say we just don't need to act here.

But I am not familiar with the topic. Check [this post](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/3750/should-the-original-intent-of-a-question-be-broadened-to-make-the-answers-more-c/3751#3751) I wrote a while back to see whether you can create a better topic everybody could be happy with.

Answer (score 2):

Well it could be merged. Since both the questions ask for the same thing, having both variations of the question with a common answer would help those searching with either of the terms