# Editing OS-specific questions or answers if the question or answer will also apply to another OS

Tags: discussion, tags, questions, editing, answers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should the original intent of a question be broadened to make the answers more canonical?](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/3750/should-the-original-intent-of-a-question-be-broadened-to-make-the-answers-more-c)

I recently found out that this question - *[How print multiple independent pages in one print job?](https://superuser.com/q/123338/10259)*, which is tagged with [linux](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/linux), and currently,  [its only answer](https://superuser.com/a/123359/10259), both also apply to Windows. (The answer, which suggested to use `pdftk`, will also work for Windows.)

To make the question [more relevant to others (as suggested by the 'How to Ask' page)](https://superuser.com/questions/how-to-ask), could I suggest an edit to this question to make it ask for solutions for Windows too (and add the [windows](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/windows) tag to it)? Its current and only answer will still apply.

Comment: You could probably remove any operating system tags, as **Pdftk** runs on Windows, Linux, Mac OS X, FreeBSD, and Solaris.

Comment: My answer over there applies here as well.