# Asking the same as existing question, but for a different platform/OS

Tags: discussion, support, questions, exact-duplicates, asking-questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should the original intent of a question be broadened to make the answers more canonical?](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/3750/should-the-original-intent-of-a-question-be-broadened-to-make-the-answers-more-c)

Sometimes there's an existing question on a topic you want answers to, but the question asks for a solutions on a particular platform / operating system (e.g. Windows) different from what you use (e.g. Linux).

Then should you post a new (near-duplicate) question that asks the same thing for a different operating system? Or should you propose an edit to the question that broadens it to apply to all OSes?