# When should the operating system be included in questions and tags?

Tags: discussion, tags

On a question I recently asked regarding passwords on PDFs, a comment was made that the OS should be included in the description and a tag for it used. When is it a good idea to include the OS? It seems like any question involving a file, format or program could somehow be related to an OS. For example if a question is about using Word 2013 is it necessary to tag it Windows? What if it's about the way Word saves its files?

In the PDF situation, it doesn't really matter what OS is used to accomplish the task so I thought specifying one would be unneeded. For example I have access to Windows 7, 8 and Ubuntu so should I use all the tags?

Comment: Somewhat related: http://meta.superuser.com/questions/3750/should-the-original-intent-of-a-question-be-broadened-to-make-the-answers-more-c

Comment: It might be necessary to say which version of Windows.  Why not be as specific as possible.  As for the reason it was asked for you to use the tag itself, that's a personal choice, but people use tags to find questions they want to answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have a community made up of users of very different platforms. In general, it is preferable to include the platform tag if it makes the slightest sense whatsoever.

Regarding your question https://superuser.com/questions/864485/how-to-remove-password-of-pdf-with-known-password, I can see where the comment is coming from, but I would agree with you here, that the tag isn't necessary.

However, a common occurrence on the site is a user asking about a problem, receiving a solution and then mentioning that it's worthless to them because they're using a Playstation, not Windows.