# Tag merge/synonym request: [touchpad] and [trackpad]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-synonym-request

These two tags mean the same thing: The pointing device usually built into laptop computers.
The tags for these should be merged.

- [touchpad](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/touchpad) x 177
- [trackpad](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/trackpad) x 52

Vote on the answers below for your preferred direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
updating post history, 70 rows affected
updating posts, 56 rows affected
updating PostTags associations, 46 rows affected
removing/renaming old tag, 0 rows affected
updating count for master tag, 1 rows affected
tag remapping of [touchpad] and [trackpad] complete!
remapping 0 synonyms
1 favorite and ignored tags remapped!
Tag Synonym trackpad -> touchpad was approved!
```

## DONE!

Answer (score 5):

### [trackpad](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/trackpad) → [touchpad](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/touchpad)

Make [trackpad](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/trackpad) a synonym to [touchpad](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/touchpad).

Answer (score 2):

## These tags don't need to be merged.

Don't create a synonym. Don't merge these tags.

Comment: (totally forgot about this one, sorry!)

Comment: ????? Why not??

Comment: @Luke Because it's a valid option in this poll. Also, you're really late. See nhinkle's answer.

Comment: I see that I"m late, but this appeared in the sidebar... Just wasn't sure that polls were made this way :P Thanks for clarification though

Comment: @Luke usually they're not. It depends on who posts a question. Explanation: http://meta.superuser.com/questions/3970/actually-changing-things-through-meta/3994#3994

Answer (score -3):

### [touchpad](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/touchpad) → [trackpad](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/trackpad)

Make [touchpad](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/touchpad) a synonym to [trackpad](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/trackpad).